# GGR and Selenoid setup issue - not able to run test on desire selenoid server machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenoid

I have some problems with GGR and Selenoid. I tried to set up and followed the documentation and below are the two ways I tried to set up GGR on a Linux machine. We have three servers selenoid1, selenoid2, and selenod3.
I am configuring GGR on the selenoid3 server

1. Setup as per documentation available in company to configure GGR

Quota file and htpasswd was created as described on the official site, quota file contains host selenoid1 and selenoid2 server, and selenoid3 works as GGR server

Start Selenoid on all three server:
`docker run -d --name selenoid -p 4444:4444 -e TZ=Etc/GMT+0 -e OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/usr/local/selenoid/video/ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/local/selenoid/config:/etc/selenoid/:ro -v /usr/local/selenoid/logs:/opt/selenoid/logs -v /usr/local/selenoid/video:/opt/selenoid/video aerokube/selenoid:latest-release -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video -timeout 3m0s -limit 8`

Start GGR on selenoid3 server:
`docker run -d --name ggr -p 4445:4444 -v /etc/grid-router:/etc/grid-router:ro aerokube/ggr:latest-release -guests-allowed -guests-quota /etc/grid-router/quota/auto`

Start GGR-UI on selenoid3 server:
`docker run -d --name ggr-ui -p 8888:8888 -v /etc/grid-router/quota/:/etc/grid-router/quota:ro aerokube/ggr-ui:latest-release`

Start Selenoid-UI on all three server:
`docker run -d --name selenoid-ui -p 8081:8080 --link ggr-ui aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest-release --selenoid-uri http://ggr-ui:8888`

With the above configuration when I run `curl http://auto:password@#{ggr_servername}:4445/status` and I get `404 page not found` when I run the test it does not connect to GGR and gives a `500` error. I also restarted all the containers again but still, I got the same error

GGR-ui log:

```
2021/07/02 21:10:32 [INIT] [Loading quota files from /etc/grid-router/quota]
2021/07/02 21:10:32 [INIT] [Listen on :8888]
```

GGR logs:

```
2021/07/02 22:00:28 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Users file is "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd"]
2021/07/02 22:00:28 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Loading configuration files from "/etc/grid-router/quota"]
```

2. As per my understanding based on the official guide on the GGR site

Quota file and htpasswd was created as described on the official site, quota file contains host selenoid1 and selenoid2 server, and selenoid3 works as GGR server

Start Selenoid on all three servers:
`docker run -d --name selenoid -p 4444:4444 -e TZ=Etc/GMT+0 -e OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/usr/local/selenoid/video/ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/local/selenoid/config:/etc/selenoid/:ro -v /usr/local/selenoid/logs:/opt/selenoid/logs -v /usr/local/selenoid/video:/opt/selenoid/video aerokube/selenoid:latest-release -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video -timeout 3m0s -limit 8`

Start GGR on selenoid3 server:
`docker run -d --name ggr -v /etc/grid-router:/etc/grid-router:ro aerokube/ggr:latest-release -guests-allowed -guests-quota /etc/grid-router/quota/auto`

Start GGR-UI on selenoid3 server:
`docker run -d --name ggr-ui -p 8888:8888 -v /etc/grid-router/quota/:/etc/grid-router/quota:ro aerokube/ggr-ui:latest-release`

Start Selenoid-UI on all three server:
`docker run -d --name selenoid-ui -p 8081:8080 aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest-release --selenoid-uri http://#{ggr_servername}:8888`

Logs GGR:

```
2021/07/02 20:51:55 [STATUS] [Failed to fetch status: Get http://#{selenoid1_name}:4444/status: dial tcp: lookup #{selenoid1} on #{selenoid1_ip}: no such host] [172.17.0.1]
2021/07/02 20:51:56 [SHUTDOWN] [Shutting down in 5m0s]
2021/07/02 21:05:00 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Users file is "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd"]
2021/07/02 21:05:00 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Loading configuration files from "/etc/grid-router/quota"]
```

Logs complain about Selenoid1 no such details for Selenoid2, I assume Selenoid2 is working and connected successfully.

Logs GGR-UI

```
2021/07/02 22:54:37 [INIT] [Loading quota files from /etc/grid-router/quota]
2021/07/02 22:54:37 [INIT] [Listen on :8888]
```

With the above configuration when I run `curl http://auto:password@#{ggr_servername}:4444/status` I get JSON response as expected and I am able to run the test but tests are executing on Selenoid3 server and chrome browser and vnc container start on selenoid3 server, I was expecting that tests will execute on Selenoid1 or Selenoid2 server but that never happens. I am not sure what is wrong with my configuration, is something I am missing?

I appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @vania-pooh can you help me on this issue?

Comment: As I said in respective Github issue, Ggr has no `/status` API.

Comment: Okay, so after using the same configuration settings (which I used for Selenium Standalone Server) I started Selenoid with GGR and that's worked as expected.